# iterating through list of list and dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this code in Python:

```
from pprint import pprint

def addDictionary(States,Transition,Languaje,Tr):
    for s in States :
         D = {}
         Transition[s] = D # this create {"state1":{"symbol1":}}
         for l in Languaje:
            for i in range(len(Tr)):
               D[l] = Tr[i][0]

def addStates(States):
     cant = int(raw_input("how many states?: "))
     for i in range(cant):
          c = "q"+str(i)
          States.append(c)

def addLan(Languaje):
     c = int(raw_input("how many symbols?: "))
     for j in range(c):
          l = raw_input("symbol: ")
          Languaje.append(l)

if __name__ == "__main__":

      States=[]
      Languaje=[]
      Transition={} #{"state":{"symbol1":"transition value","symbol2":"transition value"}}
      Tr=[["q2","q1"],["","q2"]] #transition values
      addStates(States)
      addLan(Languaje)
      addDictionary(States,Transition,Languaje,Tr)

      pprint(Transition)
```

and this is the output:

```
{'q0': {'a': '', 'b': ''}, 'q1': {'a': '', 'b': ''}}
```

what I want is something like this:

```
{'q0': {'a': 'q2', 'b': 'q1'}, 'q1': {'a': '', 'b': 'q2'}}
```

I want to put the values of the list `Tr` in my dictionary.
This is only a example code. I want to implement a Deterministic Finite Automata that I developed for a class at my University

I forgot to mention that to prove the code first input `2` ,and then `2` and then `a` and `b` because I only want to prove my code with a list of 2x2. Later I will change for a nxm list. (Sorry for my "medium" skills in English :V)

One more thing: the problem is in the the function `addDictionary()`.

Comment: Could you please rewrite your code to have sensible variable names? It makes it hard to understand what is going on when every variable is only 1 or 2 letters.

Comment: Are you using Python 2?

Comment: yeah i using Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
def addDictionary(States, Transition, Languaje, Tr):
    for s, t in zip(States, Tr):
        Transition[s] = dict(zip(Languaje, t))
```

generate this output:

```
{'q0': {'a': 'q2', 'b': 'q1'}, 'q1': {'a': '', 'b': 'q2'}}
```

for two states and symbols `a` and `b`.